# Passing Value Through Link Button in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Conditions :
I have two tables, 
category(id_kat,name_kat)
book(id_book,id_kat,name_book)

id_kat has a child and parent relations.

I'm a little bit confused using ASP.NET, especially when passing value between pages.

Now, i'm showing the category's datas with

```
<asp:listview id="listview1" runat="server" datakeynames"id_kat" datasourceID="sdskat">
//FYI sdskat is datasource for category table

<itemtemplate>
 <li>
  <asp:linkbutton id="linking" runat="server" ><%# Eval("name_kat") %></asp:linkbutton> 
 </li>
</itemtemplate>

</asp:listview>
```

The problem is, i wanted to pass "id_kat" value when i click the hyperlink. (but redirected to self page).

I want it as a query string (or another way if able).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could use an `<a>` tag instead of `<asp:LinkButton>` if you simply need to display a link.

Comment: i've tried it before. For example in php i can do it like this :
<a href="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?id_kat=$id_katdb">$name_katdb </a>

but in this ASP.NET i'm a lil bit confused what is the equal of $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] ??

(i know the equal is Request.FilePath, but how do i put it in the aspx?? i always ended to an error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're linking to the same page with different query string parameters, you only need to include ? and after.

```
<a href="?id=<%# Eval("id") %>"><%# Eval("name_kat") %></a>
```

Comment: i think this is the answer. :)

Sorry i'm very newbie in ASP.NET, i'm just helping my friends now with her major project.

Actually i'm a VB.NET :) 

Thanks a lot

Comment: i just never tried 

<a href="?id=...."> i thought it would be an error since we didn't mention the page.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `<asp:hyperlink id="linking" runat="server" ><%# Eval("name_kat") %></asp:hyperlink>` instead.  You can then add your url in the `navigateURL` attribute and append your id_kat on there.

Something like this should work:

`<asp:hyperlink id="linking" runat="server" navigateURL="~/page.aspx?id_kat=<%# Eval('id_kat') %>" ><%# Eval("name_kat") %></asp:hyperlink>`

the `<asp:hyperlink>` tag is essentially the  tag but using a server side control.

If you have to use a linkbutton then in your code behind you can append the id_kat to the querystring and then `response.redirect(url)` to the new page.

Comment: I guess i have the answer already above. :)

But i appreciate your effort Robert. Actually, the real problem is i wanted to change your "~/page.aspx" into "self redirect" code. But i found it with <a href="?id_kat=..."> would work. 

Thanks anyway for your answer Robert. :)

Comment: You could do the same thing in an asp:hyperlink as it's just a n asp.net version of the a href tag. Good you got the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a regular anchor?

```
<a href='foo.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id_kat") %>'><%# Eval("name_kat") %></a>
```

Comment: Nah, it could be easy if i know the page i wanted to redirect. 
but, i wanted it to redirect to its own page. 
(in php it would be $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]).

how do i put it in :
<a href='bla..bla..?id=.....>

i can't find the solution for the bla-bla things. (redirect to itself i mean)

Comment: @ArvidTheodorus - that's a cool PHP function, but I'm not sure what the asp.net equivalent would be

Comment: Anyway i appreciate your answer Adam. :)

At last you've been put a lot of thought about my unnecessary code :p

Thanks Adam. :)